# Calculate the subspace generated

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening!

I have a lot of doubts and I'm not sure how to calculate the subspace of $\mathbb{R_5[x]}$ generated by these polynomials. The calculation that I must do is the following: $span(\{1,3x^2-5,x^4\})$?

My work:

I posed the linear combination of the polynomials and equated it to a generic element of $\mathbb{R_5[x]}$ , then I know that a system of equations must be solved, but I do not see how to put it. Can you give me a hand, please? I would be very grateful.

$cx^4+3bx^2-5b+a=a_5x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any element in the subspace is a linear combination of $1,$ $3x^2-5$ and $x^4.$ We have that

$$\begin{cases}1&=1\cdot 1\\ x^2&=\dfrac13\cdot (3x^2-5)+\dfrac35 \cdot1\\x^ 4&=1\cdot x^4\end{cases}$$

Thus $a+bx^2+cx^4$ is in the subspace.

Now, is $x$ or $x^5$ in the subspace? No. Why? Because we cannot write them as a linerar combination of $1,$ $3x^2-5$ and $x^4.$

Comment: May I add that $\{1,3x^2-5,x^4\}$ is free in $\mathbb{R}_5[x]$, since degree-wise echelonned. Hence, the subspace it spans has dimension $3$.

Comment: @C.Falcon Of course. Feel free to add it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I am new to the area. Could be more clear please, I would like to know the parametric equations that describe the subspace that I want to calculate.

Comment: From the equality $cx^4+3bx^2-5b+a=a_5x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ you get that $a_5=a_3=0.$

Comment: @mfl And the other components? How would I say this set by understanding?

Comment: You can solve it by using the identities in the answer.

Comment: @mfl The final set would be? $\{a_5x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0\mid a_5=a_3=0\}$

Comment: Do you mean $\{a_5x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0\mid a_5=a_3=a_1=0\}$

Comment: yes, then $span(\{1,3x^2-5,x^4\})=\{a_5x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0 \in\mathbb{R}_5[x] \mid a_5=a_3=a_1=0\}$? this is correct?

Comment: Yes. It is correct.

Comment: Then the subspace generated by these polynomials is $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$?

Comment: No. $\mathbb{R}_3[x]=\{a+bx+cx^2\}\ne \{a+bx^2+cx^4\}.$

Comment: @mfl Thank you very much really. You have been very attentive with my doubts. This topic is new to me and currently I do not have a linear algebra teacher, I am studying on my own. I will continue to do exercises, but I would like you to do me the favor of advising me. How can I contact you? Greetings from Venezuela.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}[x]_5$ has $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}$ as a canonical basis. You can see that the basis of your subspace already contains $1$ and $x^4$. What about the element $3x^2-5$?

Call it $v$. Changing it with $v + a +bx^4$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ does not change the generated subspace (because it is an elementary operation), and the same is true for scalar multiplication. With this procedure you should be able to replace $v$ with a more familiar vector of $\mathbb{R}[x]_5$ while still having a basis of the subspace. The answer will then be clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I am new to the area. Could be more clear please, I would like to know the parametric equations that describe the subspace that I want to calculate.